# Getting timestamp using strftime

Tags: c

I have time in seconds `long tv_sec`, and I want to get the correct date, and time, using the format  `%Y-%m-%d %X`, using the function `stftime`. 
So I have the time stamps in seconds and I want to convert it using `stftime`.

This is my trial

```
struct tm dateStruct;
  memset(dateStruct, 0, sizeof(struct tm));

  gmtime(&timestampInSecs,dateStruct);

  char buffer[80];

  strftime(buffer,80,"%Y-%m-%d %X", dateStruct);
  printf("Formatted date & time : |%s|\n", buffer );
```

Comment: Take a look [HERE](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/strftime.3.html) and do not ask so simple question before at least put the name of function on google...

Comment: Well [`strftime`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/chrono/strftime) uses the time from a [`struct tm`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/chrono/tm) pointer. If you follow the reference links I'm sure you should find out a way to get from your time in seconds to the formatted string.

Comment: @JoachimPileborg  I have edited the post and wrote some code, is that correct ?

Comment: @LPs Is my above code correct?

Comment: Do you have time in seconds in `long tv_sec` from what source?  Time in seconds since when?  If you are using GNU functions, `tv_sec` is type `time_t`, not necessarily `long` and typically represents seconds since Jan 1, 1970 - universal time.   OTOH if you ave some other source of "seconds", the solution is different.  Post how code "have time in seconds long `tv_sec`" and if you want the date to be local time or universal time ((UTC](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Coordinated_Universal_Time))

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ensure that `timestampInSecs` is `time_t` type and try this:

```
    char buffer[80];

    strftime(buffer,80,"%Y-%m-%d %X", gmtime(&timestampInSecs));

    printf("Formatted date & time : |%s|\n", buffer );
```

**EDIT**

Example: if you have `timestampInSecs` that represent seconds from `1/1/2000` you must compensate the variable with all seconds from `1/1/1970` (epoch in Linux time.h)
From 1/1/1970 to 1/1/2000 we have:

- `10957` days
- `262968` hours
- `946684800` seconds

At the end you have to sum `946684800` to your variable to be able to use `strftime` as shown in my code.

Then what you must do is to calculate seconds between `1/1/1970` and your start date and time (the date and time of `timestampInSecs=0`)

Comment: I only have the time in seconds not in timet_t

Comment: Time_t are seconds from epoch

Comment: my question is If I have the time in seconds, just in a single variable can I convert it to strftime ?

Comment: @AndreAhmed Your seconds start from some point in the past. Linux time.h calculate date and time since 1/1/1970. Then you must add seconds from 1/1/1970 to your start date and time and then use the code posted.

Comment: strftime(buffer,80,"%Y-%m-%d %X", gmtime_r(&value->timestamp,&timeStruct));
is that correct? where value->timeStamp is the seconds

Comment: "Time_t are seconds from epoch" is not supported by the C spec.  "The range and precision of times representable in clock_t and time_t are
implementation-defined."  C11dr §7.27.1 4.  Even the epoch of Jan 1, 1970 is not specified.  So this answer may work for OP yet fail on another machine.

Comment: @chux Are you kidding me? -1 for such a picky comment? I think stakoverflow aim to answer to OP questions, not to give a full cross platforms unswer. BTW I wrote "epoch in Linux time.h" that is crystal...

Comment: Aside from unqualified assertions like "Time_t are seconds from epoch" 1) Code should rather than magic numbers like `946684800` set the fields of a `struct tm` to the epoch and add the seconds to its fields, then call `mktime()` 2) address the issue of timezone as *nix `time_t` represents universal time yet code is using `mktime()` which is local making `946684800` wrong, unless near the UK.  3)  make clear OP's likely incorrect type of `long tv_sec` (expect  `time_t tv_sec`) 4)  avoid skipping glossing over return value of `gmtime()` for new users.

Comment: Concerning DV: rather than rail on those that DV _and_ comment, remaining courteous in comments encourages explanations and resolution.